# WKHTMLTOPDF: How to disable header on the first page

Tags: header, wkhtmltopdf

wkhtml doesn´t repeat table elements "th" on every page like it should. So I thought it could be possible to simply use the --header-html option and add the table headers manually this way. But I don´t want them on the first page, since there are table headers already, plus some other first page stuff... I found some JS solution, but its too much complicated for me, since I know just the very basics of JS... Any ideas?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean. Doesn't repeat table elements on every page? Do you mean table elements in the page headers? Do you mean it should add <th> elements to each table in your source document? Table headers and page headers are two different beasts, when the manual talks about headers it means the content of what gets put into every page of the generated PDF document :)

Comment: I mean that: The table headers doesn´t repeat on every page. For that reason I want to display page headers instead (which will contain "table headers"), generated by wkhtml. They are displayed correctly, but I don´t want them on the first page.

Comment: i need to do this for python if you have an answer for that too, thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Did you try the JS solution? It's actually not that complicated. I just did a test with a long html file that contained a table that is split into many different pages and I managed to remove the headers from page 1 and 3 using this header file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script>
        function subst() {
          var vars={};
          var x=document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
          for (var i in x) {var z=x[i].split('=',2);vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);}
          var x=['frompage','topage','page','webpage','section','subsection','subsubsection'];
          for (var i in x) {
            var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
            for (var j=0; j<y.length; ++j) y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];

            if(vars['page'] == 1){ // If page is 1, set FakeHeaders display to none
               document.getElementById("FakeHeaders").style.display = 'none';
            }

            if(vars['page'] == 3) { // If page is 3, set FakeHeaders display to none
                document.getElementById("FakeHeaders").style.display = 'none';
            }
          }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="border:0;margin:0;" onload="subst()">
        <table style="border-bottom: 1px solid pink; width: 100%; margin-bottom:5px;" id="FakeHeaders">
          <tr>
            <th>Your awesome table column header 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th style="text-align:right">
                Page <span class="page"></span>/<span class="topage"></span>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

They key points to not there is that the table "headers" are contained in a table that has the ID "FakeHeaders". The javascript function subst() is run when the body is loaded and during the function it checks if the current page is 1 or if the current page is 3 and if it is, the FakeHeaders is set invisible. You will need to play with the margins and CSS to get it to look like you want but this Should work.

This is a known problem with wkhtmltopdf and most likely it won't be fixed any time soon, see [issue 566 in the issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=566). I see the JavaScript option as the only usable workaround, but you can try playing around with divs or manually splitting the tables if your input html, style and page sizes/margins are very predictable - but be warned, it will be really annoying.

Comment: I can´t split it manually because there are various line heights... But: I tried this JS solution. I got it exactly like you, in head element. I added function call and id, but it does nothing:/ ...

Comment: Oh I read it wrong... I skipped the part where you say "header file"... Now it works just fine... Thanks!!! :)

Comment: Great that you got it working, paging can cause some annoying issues! :)

Comment: Im experiencing annoying issues all the time with wkhtml :D But that´s just cause Im not very skilled :)

Comment: @Nenotlep I got this to work in the footer-html first try, but not using header-html, which display nothing. I'm using the PHP-WKHTMLtoPDF wrapper, but I don't think it is related to the wrapper as the command goes out.  Have you had this happen?

Comment: Yeah this doesn't remove the margins added to the first page, though, so it still makes for a complete mess.

Comment: @Mir haven't used wkhtmltopdf in a while, but I think that's just not possible. Maybe you could create the coverpage separately and pdftk it together or something, I did that sometimes. Butif print layout is very important and precise for you I'd recommend XSLT/Apache fop or maybe trying PrinceXML, if you have the finance for it.

Comment: @Nenotlep We used to use FO, but we're using the contents as both an HTML page and a PDF, and we don't want to build it twice. That's probably the most flexible solution though. We just decided to drop the page headers altogether.

Answer (score 2):

If you can split the first page alone as a separate html, you can do this by using 'cover' in WKHTMLTOPDF.

```
PDFKit.new(url, :header_html => header_url, :cover => cover_url).
```

Comment: The problem right now is that cover do remove header/footer but keep the reserved space in the page. So in result, lets say you need a different header or a full page background color, you cant with 0.12.5

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem in which I had used `WKHTMLTOPDF` header/footer and I wanted to remove them from the cover page. The issue was that the maximum height of header/footer was still appearing on all pages including the cover page.

The solution that clicked my mind and saved the day was that I generated two `WKHTMLTOPDF` files, one with header/footer on all pages and the other one without any header/footer. I then picked cover page from `WKHTMLTOPDF` generated file without header/footer and rest of the pages from the other `WKHTMLTOPDF` generated file with header/footer on all pages. I used `PDF Merger` library in `PHP` to merge selected pages of two `WKHTMLTOPDF` generated 'PDF' files to generate single `PDF` file with cover page and header/footer on rest of the pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var pdfInfo = {};
    var x = document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');

    for (var i in x) { var z = x[i].split('=',2); pdfInfo[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]); }

    function getPdfInfo() {
        var page = pdfInfo.page || 1;

        if(page != 1) {
            document.getElementById('pHeader').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    getPdfInfo();
</script>
```

Comment: Add some comments to your answer

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Nenotlep's answer didn't worked for me. It removed only page number..

So I created a class with a display: none; and simply added it. It worked this way.

```js
function pagination() {
  var vars = {};
  var x = document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
  for (var i in x) {
    var z = x[i].split('=', 2);
    vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);
  }
  var x = ['frompage', 'topage', 'page', 'webpage', 'section', 'subsection', 'subsubsection'];
  for (var i in x) {
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < y.length; ++j) y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];

    if (vars['page'] == 1) {
      var element = document.getElementById("pager");
      element.classList.add("pager-hidden");
    }
  }

}
```

```css
.pager {
  font-size: 0.09375in;
  padding-right: 1.00003in;
  text-align: right;
  letter-spacing: 0.01042in;
  padding-bottom: 0.37501in;
}

.pager.pager-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body onload="pagination()">

  <div class="pager" id="pager">
    <div class="pager-pages">Page <span class="page"></span> / <span class="topage"></span></div>
  </div>

</body>
```