# WKHTMLtoPDF header file content not displayed in PDF

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to hide the header page number on the first page using this example I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11950452/1148107).  Which only works if I use it with footer-html and doesn't show/hide anything if I use it with header-html.  Originally I was trying to augment this [solution](http://biostall.com/wkhtmltopdf-add-header-footer-to-only-first-last-page) which also worked using footer-html, but since I couldn't get it to work in the header I kept on searching.  I've tried it with and without 'header-center' => '[[page]]' in case using this with header-html caused conflicts.  Anyone been able to get this to work in the headers recently?  I'm using PHPWKHTMLtoPDF wrapper version 1.2.6-dev if that helps with a up to date version of WKHTMLtoPDF, since the newest version of PHPWKHTMLtoPDF uses namespaces and we're using CodeIgniter 2.x-dev, which doesn't support them (or play well can't remember).

```
    // Create document PDF
    $pdf = new $this->wkhtmltopdf;

    // Locate WkHtmlToPdf executable for Windows
    if( $pdf->getIsWindows() ) 
    {
        $pdf->setOptions( array( 'binPath' => 'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe', 
                                 'no-outline',
                                 'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                                 'margin-top'    => 30,
                                 'margin-right'  => 20,
                                 'margin-bottom' => 30,
                                 'margin-left'   => 20,

                                 // Default page options
                                 'disable-smart-shrinking',
                                 'user-style-sheet' => 'pdf.css',
                                 'header-html' => dirname(__FILE__) . '\..\views\wkhtmltopdf\header.html'
        ) );
    }

    // Generate document fields
    $docInputs = $this->generate_inputs( $inputs, json_decode( $this->load->file( APPPATH . '/mapping/' . $document['mapping'], TRUE ), TRUE ) );

    // Merge document fields into HTML exported Word files
    $docHTML = $this->parser->parse( 'docs/' . $document['html'], $docInputs, TRUE );

    // Add HTML as page, along with option for page header
    $pdf->addPage( $docHTML, array( 'header-center' => '[[page]]',
                                    'header-spacing' => '10',
                                    'header-font-name' => 'Times New Roman'
    ) );
```

Comment: Hmm... good idea to make this a separate question :). Can you show us your header HTML code?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to add the `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the header file, WKHTMLtoPDF [issue #46](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/46) for version 0.12

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I've been searching for this one

Comment: OMG the time I lost before finding this :( TY

Answer (score 5):

I'm posting this answer because this happened to me and this might also be a reason.

I'v also noticed if you set the header css to this. It will not show the header.

```
html{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for those header isn't show up in wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have version with patched qt

[image]